# ansible copy ssh keys to multiple users' home directory

Tags: users, openssh, ansible

I have ssh keypair on my ansible_host, which I want to copy to multiple user's authorized keys on target host.

I'm trying with-item construct, but it complaints about .pub key not an invalid key
here's what I'm trying.

```
- authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.user }}"
    key: "{{ item.key }}"
  with_items:
        - { user: "user1", key: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" }
        - { user: "user2", key: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" }
```

ERROR: `"msg": "invalid key specified: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to copy your key to multiple users you can do it like that :

```yaml
- authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.user }}"
    key: "{{ lookup('file', lookup('env','HOME') + '/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
  with_items:
        - { user: "user1" }
        - { user: "user2" }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are inserting the key as a string into the key field.

You should use the [file lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html).

In your case it should look something like this (not tested, not entirely sure about the brackets ):

```yaml
- authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.user }}"
    key: "{{ item.key }}"
  with_items:
        - { user: "user1", key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}" }
        - { user: "user2", key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}" }
```